# use sql stored procedure to insert data which is returned from a query stored in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

sql server 2005
I have a stored procedure which I used to insert data into a table.  Some of the data will need to come from the results of executing a query that is stored in a separate table.

The main problem that I keep hitting is not being able to properly execute the returned query.  I have tried creating several functions over the past couple of days based on other posts that I have read, but I keep hitting sql errors with exec, execute, sp_executesql, etc.

I am going to paste several scripts that you can use to replicate my environment.  I am hoping that someone can please provide an actual code sample which will execute the returned query for use within the stored proc insert function.

Thank you!!!

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CLIENT](
    [cli_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [cli_first_name] [varchar](100) NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PK__CLIENT__07F6335A] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [cli_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO


INSERT INTO CLIENT (cli_first_name, cli_last_name) values ('tom', 'smith');
go



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ASSESSMENT_DATALABEL_LIST](
    [adl_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [BoundName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Query] [ntext] NOT NULL,
    [KeyFieldName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ASSESSMENT_DATALABEL_LIST] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [adl_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT INTO ASSESSMENT_DATALABEL_LIST (Name, BoundName, Query, KeyFieldName, Status) 
values ('Name, First', 'cli_first_name', 'select IsNull(cli_first_name,'''') as cli_first_name FROM CLIENT WHERE cli_id = @KeyFieldValue', 'cli_ID', 'Active')
go

INSERT INTO ASSESSMENT_DATALABEL_LIST (Name, BoundName, Query, KeyFieldName, Status) 
values ('Name, Last', 'cli_last_name', 'select IsNull(cli_last_name,'''') as cli_last_name FROM CLIENT WHERE cli_id = @KeyFieldValue', 'cli_ID', 'Active')
go


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Item_Source]
(   
    [Item_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ItemType] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ItemCaption] [nvarchar] (50) NULL,
      [adl_ID] [int] NOT NULL
)
go

INSERT INTO Item_Source
(ItemType, ItemCaption, adl_ID) values 
('DATALABEL', 'First Name',1)
go

INSERT INTO Item_Source
(ItemType, ItemCaption, adl_ID) values 
('DATALABEL', 'Last Name',2)
go

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Item_Destination]
(
    [ItemType] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ItemCaption] [nvarchar] (50) NULL,
      [ItemValue] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)
go


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertStuff]

@cli_id int

AS

INSERT INTO Item_Destination
(ItemType, ItemCaption, ItemValue)
SELECT
ItemType, ItemCaption, [[[ VALUE OF EXECUTED QUERY FROM ADL TABLE --- dbo.FunctionToGetResultsOfStoredQuery(Item_Source.adl_id, @cli_id) ]]]
FROM Item_Source WHERE Item_Source.Item_ID IN (1,2)

-- this insert will insert both Item_Source rows into Item_Dest with one call.  The first row should have an ItemValue of Tom, the second row should have an ItemValue of Smith
GO
```

Comment: `INSERT dbo.SomeTable(SomeColumn) SELECT SomeColumn FROM dbo.OtherTable WHERE ...;`

Comment: What should we do with the @KeyFieldValue?

Comment: sorry, thanks for asking!  the @ KeyFieldValue will be the @ cli_id which is passed to the spInsertStuff proc.

Comment: Fresh code coming your way

Answer (score 2):

You may check [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/53e23/3)

The code of the Stored Procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertStuff]

@cli_id int

AS


DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ADL_ID AS INT

DECLARE MyCURSOR
CURSOR FOR 
SELECT QUERY, ADL_ID FROM ASSESSMENT_DATALABEL_LIST

OPEN MyCURSOR   
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCURSOR INTO @SQL, @ADL_ID   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   

        SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL,'@KeyFieldValue',@cli_id)
        DECLARE @Temp AS TABLE ([Value] [nvarchar](50))

        INSERT INTO @Temp
        EXEC (@SQL)

        INSERT INTO Item_Destination
        (ItemType, ItemCaption, ItemValue)
        SELECT
        ItemType, ItemCaption, (SELECT [Value] FROM @Temp)
        FROM Item_Source 
        WHERE Item_Source.adl_ID = @ADL_ID   

        DELETE FROM @Temp

        FETCH NEXT FROM MyCURSOR INTO @SQL, @ADL_ID   
END   

CLOSE MyCURSOR   
DEALLOCATE MyCURSOR

GO
```

Comment: thank you very much, this looks like an excellent start, but I am running into a problem.  I apologize, I should have posted my question with SomeTable containing more than one field.  I have edited my post so that it now has two fields.  One field should contain the value returned from the stored query, the other field can contain anything for our purposes here.  When I try to modify your solution to accommodate the second field I get syntax errors on the exec call.  thanks again for any help :)

Comment: What value is going to go into that field?

Comment: See my Edited solution.

Comment: sorry for the confusion.  i tried to simplify my original post because i was expecting that the answer would be a function of some kind that i could plug into my environment on my own.  I was wrong.  The solution you have provided does match my question but it does not fully meet my needs.  sorry for any waste of time, and again, thank you for any more help that you can offer.

Comment: what i really really need is to do multiple inserts in one call, using the returned query value as one of the fields, such as

insert into SomeTable (SomeField, SomeOtherField)
SELECT [the returned query value], othertable.field
FROM othertable
WHERE othertable.id IN (1,2,3,4,5)

Comment: Can you check now? I am storing the return value in a table variable and then use that to fill the desired table. From there you can do whatever queries you like with the @Temp table.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work because 'someothervalue' needs to come from a table other than @Temp.  Is it possible to put the [select stored query, execute stored query, return result] functionality into a Function?  Then I could do something like:

INSERT into SomeTable (SomeField, SomeOtherField) SELECT dbo.GetData(othertable.adl_id, @cli_id), othertable.field FROM othertable WHERE othertable.id IN (1,2,3,4,5).

Comment: 'someothervalue' is not comming from @Temp. In my example it is hardcoded but you could have something like: `SELECT T.Value, S.SomeOtherFieldValue FROM @Temp T CROSS JOIN SomeOtherTable S`

Comment: when we query the ADL table it needs to be by adl_ID, which in your join example would be S.adl_id.  But S does not exist above the Insert block when we would populate the @Temp.  That was why I was thinking of a function that could be called inline and passed the adl_ID.  Is there a way to run your process within the Insert's Select block, or anywhere else where we can feed it each row's adl_id?

Comment: Sorry, but i don't get it exactly. Can you Update the question with your need?

Comment: yes, done.  so sorry that I keep moving the goal posts on you.  you're getting a green check no matter what, thanks for your help ;)

Comment: Sorry for missing it yesterday. What do you think of this update? I have added the value in a variable, so now you can use it however you need. Let me know what you think.

Comment: You're doing me the favor, certainly don't mind you missing a day!  thanks again for the help.  I'm going to mess with this a bit tomorrow morning but I think we're still going to have the same problem of not being able to pass the adl_id at the right time of the process.  I'll supply a more detailed example of the insert proc so that you can see where I'm hitting the snag.  Thanks again!

Comment: I have updated several of the tables in the script to give a more detailed example of what I need to do and where I'm hitting the trouble. thanks again for your help with this.

Comment: I have updated the code. I haven't checked SQLFiddle today, but i have a new version of the code.

Comment: thanks once again!  this may be getting closer but there a couple of things that I don't think will work for my situation.

1. Looping through and executing every query within the ADL table will use way too much processing time.  There could be 100 different rows/queries in that table and we may only need a few.  2. adl_ID is not a required field in Item_Source.  Many Item_Source rows may not have an adl_id, so it looks like these rows would be missed entirely.

Comment: 3. multiple rows in Item_Source could potentially have the same adl_id, so Delete From @Temp would probably cause issues.

I keep coming back to thinking that the most simple and straight forward solution would be to write a function (or set of functions) that executes a stored query and returns the result.  This function could be called inline and passed the necessary parameters.  However, I cannot for the life of me get a function to execute the query and return the value.  I am guessing that maybe you're hitting the same problem?

Comment: To be honest i haven't tried a function. I'll see what i can do.

Comment: gonna be afk for a few days..., will check back next week, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, a function is not possible to execute dynamic sql

Comment: thank you very much for all of your help with this.  I should be able to make use of some of your code and will need to figure out  a work around for the rest.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry i couldn't think of something else